# What does SP in '2.11.0.SP5' mean?

Tags: java, apache, xerces

I have a need to use a version of xerces that that does not use xml-apis; there is some legacy code that does not play well with it.

I found the following which looks like it will do the trick.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0.SP5</version>
</dependency>
```

But I am not sure what the 'SP5' means. More specifically, I do not know if this can be trusted for a production system.

Comment: possibly service pack?

Comment: @mangoHero1, that is a good guess but if so, any idea why there was a service pack or what was added in that sp?

Comment: The `SPx` suffix seems to be JBoss fixes to the standard Apache Xerces code: [JBoss Xerces Fork (JBoss Community Fixes)](https://github.com/jboss/xerces/tree/jboss-2.11.0.SP5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a fork with fixes from JBoss community.